# Validate user input dates are in given date range using javascript

Tags: javascript, validation, date, date-range

I am new to php and javascript. this is what put me in to trouble
There are two dates given by administration.

```
var a="24/05/2013";
var b="26/05/2013";
```

Assume if user select check in Date as : `17/05/2013` and check out date as : `30/05/2013`.
as you can see, those selected dates are in between above mentioned dates (var a and var b).
so how can i validate that scenario using JAVASCRIPT.

need a support on this.

thanks in advance

Comment: http://www.the-art-of-web.com/javascript/validate-date/#.UYySK0r2Di4

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
function dateCheck() {
    var fDate = new Date("24/05/2013");
    var lDate; = new Date("26/05/2013");
    fDate = Date.parse(document.getElementById("fDate").value);
    lDate = Date.parse(document.getElementById("lDate").value);

    if(fDate <= lDate) {
        alert("true");
        return true;
    }
    alert("false");
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll do it like this:

```
function dateCheck() {
    var a = new Date("24/05/2013");
    var b = new Date("26/05/2013");
    var checkinDate = Date.parse(document.getElementById("checkinDate").value);
    var checkoutDate = Date.parse(document.getElementById("checkoutDate").value);

    return((checkinDate >= a && checkinDate <= b) && 
       (checkoutDate <= b && checkoutDate >= a) && 
       (checkoutDate > checkinDate))            
}
```

Edit: As per clarification with OP

```
function dateCheck() {
        var a = new Date("24/05/2013");
        var b = new Date("26/05/2013");
        var checkinDate = Date.parse(document.getElementById("checkinDate").value);
        var checkoutDate = Date.parse(document.getElementById("checkoutDate").value);

        return(( a > checkinDate && a < checkoutDate) && 
           (b < checkoutDate && b > checkinDate) && 
           (checkoutDate > checkinDate))            
    }
```

Comment: `if(condition){return true;}else{return false}` always puzzled me… why not `return condition`?

Comment: @AnkitJaiswal.above fundtion is not working when i put 17/05/2013 and 30/05/2013.can you help me on this?

Comment: @DamithaPathmaperuma 17/05/2013 and 30/05/2013 do not exist between 24/05/2013 and 26/05/2013. As per question, the check-in and check-out time should exist between range a and b. Isn't it what you wanted?

Comment: @AnkitJaiswal.24/05/2013 and 26/05/2013 are in between 17/05/2013 and 30/05/2013.user cannot make a booking including 24/05/2013 and 26/05/2013. hope you understand it?

Answer (score 0):

Try this :-

```
 var fdt= new Date("20/02/2013");
    var tdt = new Date("10/05/2013");

function validateFromAndToDate(fdt,tdt){

    var dt1  = dte1.value.substring(0,2); 
    var mon1 = dte1.value.substring(3,5); 
    var yr1  =dte1.value.substring(6,10); 

    var dt2  = dte2.value.substring(0,2); 
    var mon2 = dte2.value.substring(3,5); 
    var yr2  = dte2.value.substring(6,10); 
    var date1 = new Date(yr1, mon1-1, dt1); 
    var date2 = new Date(yr2, mon2-1, dt2); 

        if (date2<date1){
            alert("Date period must be within the given date!");
            return false
        }
    return true
 }
```

It works fine.